# Blender grease pencil rendering a vector image

Tags: grease-pencil

Now, I guess I have never tried it but, is it possible to draw an image with the grease pencil and export it as a vector image? I have seen people do the same thing except they put like an SVG (or something vector format) into blender and then there is a grease pencil layer with the image there now.

can you export a grease pencil image into a vector image file?